# Settings API Message Error is global

Tags: plugins, settings-api

Am not shure how to realy use settings api for showing error messages on my menu-page. For example i create menu page (eng.product)and there i register two input text fields like example. After submiting  my form in my custom page error message is the some in all options page "reading, writing, premalinks, ...etc".
Whay is not only on that page what i create.

Here is code how i use error funcition. Maybe this is wrong way how i use it, for that i post this question:

```
        /**
         * Init Admin Options
         *
         */
        public function initAdminOptions()
        {
            // Init settings options
            $this->createSettingSection();
            $this->createOptionFields();
            $this->registerSettingsOptions();

            $this->options = get_option('isl_ecomerce');

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                $this->options = array(
                    'product_name'  => sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_name']),
                    'product_price' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_price']),
                    'product_desc'  => esc_textarea($_POST['product_desc'])
                );
                // Validate fields
                if($this->options['product_name'] == '' || $this->options['product_price'] == '') {
                    add_settings_error('product_message', '', 'All field required!', 'error');

                    return;
                }else {
                    // Check if table exist
                    if( false === get_option('isl_ecomerce')) {
                        add_option('isl_ecomerce', $this->options);
                        add_settings_error('product_message', '', 'Settings Saved...', 'updated');
                    }else {
                        // Already exist? Update it
                        update_option('isl_ecomerce', $this->options);
                        add_settings_error('isl_ecomerce', '', 'Settings Updated..', 'updated');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And i register hook for settings_error

```
/**
 * Settings Errors 
 *
 */
public function option_notices()
{
        settings_errors('product_message');
}
```

In my __construct i do :

```
 add_action('admin_notices', array(&$this, 'option_notices'));
```

And options page

```
/**
 * Create Options Page
 *
 */
public function createOptionsPage()
{
    add_menu_page(
        __('Products', 'domain'),
        __('Products', 'domain'),
        'manage_options',
        'products_page',
        array(&$this, 'optionsPageCallback')
    );
}
```

After this i have the some message "All field required!", "Settings Saved...", "settings updated..." on all pages in wp-admin. How to show only in my page

Answer (score 1):

The *setting* that is the first parameter is the not the option key. It is the key that you would've registered using [register_setting](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting)

```
register_setting( 'settings_unique_key4172_91h, 'option_key', 'name_of_sanitiser_function' );
```

Then you can add settings errors like this, **inside** the callback

```
function name_of_sanitiser_function(){

    add_settings_error(
        'settings_unique_key4172_91h',
        esc_attr( 'settings_updated' ),
        $message,
        $type
    );

}
```

You might like a few tutorials. I agree personally that it is very confusing:

http://www.presscoders.com/2010/05/wordpress-settings-api-explained/

http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/

Comment: so if i add new `add_settings_error('my_err')` i must `register_settings()` for all added settings error?

Comment: No, the idea is that your 'setting' has a lot of fields that are stored together in one array. Your individual fields are handled via http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field For the rest you should read a tutorial.

Comment: I will first read mora in this tutorials what u post. Thanks

Comment: I read all from this two link what u post. I dont found any example about using erorrs

Comment: Those were for understanding Settings API in general. See my edit above for the short answer. The add_settings_error should be called inside the callback function.

Comment: I found where i do mistake`if(isset($_POST['submit']))` submit is global and will be rendered on all wp forms. When i change name of submit now all work fine. Ur post is good and help me to understand some things. One more this work good but all my errors is show above the admin_page_title not below. Does exist any tip to render that notices below the title ? Myb geting `$_REQUEST['settings_updated']` and than print it ?